# Do you think it's a good schema.prisma?

Tags: mongodb, next.js

i'm trying to learn backend with Next JS, and i'm using Prisma + MongoDB. I want to create a simple website with a user with a cart and some products. here my schema :

```
    model User {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name      String
  nickname  String
  password  String   @unique
  email     String   @unique
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  cart      Cart[]
  role      Role     @default(ADMIN)
}

model Product {
  id             String           @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name           String           @unique
  description    String
  image          String
  price          Float
  stock          Boolean          @default(true)
  isNew          Boolean          @default(true)
  createdAt      DateTime         @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime         @updatedAt
  productsOnCart ProductsOnCart[]
}

model Cart {
  id             String           @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId         String           @db.ObjectId
  user           User             @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  createdAt      DateTime         @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime         @updatedAt
  productsOnCart ProductsOnCart[]
}

model ProductsOnCart {
  id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  cart      Cart    @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id])
  cartId    String  @db.ObjectId
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId String  @db.ObjectId

  @@unique([cartId, productId])
}

enum Role {
  USER
  ADMIN
}
```

After that i gonna try to show all product from ProductsOnCart, if cart.userId === user.id and productsOnCart.cartId === cart.id, then i gonna map all products (same thing here, i should map all products and if products.id === productsOnCart.productId )

I'm sorry if my english is bad, isn't my native language.

Do you think is a good method to create a user cart ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

## YAGNI

```
model User {
  id        ...
  name      ...
  nickname  String
```

[YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).
I'm concerned that `nickname` is a v2 kind of thing that you
aren't quite ready for yet. Get something up and running,
and *then* worry about adding polish.

---

## authentication

```
  password  String   @unique
```

Oh, my goodness, so many things in that one line.

You didn't call it a `pw_hash`, so I'm concerned
that (gasp!) you're storing cleartext passwords.
Which would be Bad.
Especially if someone compromises your server and publishes those passwords.

The UNIQUE key is inviting attackers to replay
their dictionaries of popular passwords against your site.
If user `mallory` is prohibited from changing her password
to "secret123", then she *knows* for certain that one of
your users is definitely using that password!
So she will try it against all usernames that she is
either aware of or can guess.

Prefer to store a hash, generated by
[argon2id()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).
(It will be a salted hash, which is a good thing.)
Now Mallory will be forced to spend a quarter second
or so of CPU time on each dictionary probe,
even after a breach leaks your database contents.

---

## unique email

```
  email     String   @unique
```

I like it.

But it's pretty rude to downcase someone's email address.
Strictly speaking the characters before the `@`-sign are
not yours to interpret -- they are case sensitive,
interpreted by the distant MX mail exchanger.
And I don't see a pair of fields for storing original + downcased
versions of this string.

So maybe omit the UNIQUE index?
And worry about dups at the app level? (in a case-insensitive way)
I don't have a *strong* feeling on this, it just seems slightly off is all.

I *do* like the pair of timestamps.
Defaulting `role` to ADMIN instead of USER seems like the wrong choice.

---

## SKU

```
model Product {
  id             ...
  name           String           @unique
```

I really like this.

But I suspect that `name` might not be the appropriate identifier.

Prefer `partNum` or `sku` (stocking control unit).

Also, I'm skeptical that `price` value should be optional.

Maybe spell `stock` as `inStock`?

The `isNew` column sounds like trouble to me.
("New" with respect to what? And will it *stay* "new"?)
Recommend you just delete it.
Or perhaps create a timestamp column to model the concept that you care about.

Since I don't understand what `productsOnCart` describes, recommend you delete it.
It *sounds* like it's related to a user's shopping cart,
which would be quite a different concept.
Or maybe you're getting at the notion of an `Inventory` table?
In which case the `stock` column definitely needs to go.
Keep inventory details separate from product details.

---

## denorm

```
model Cart {
  id             ...
  userId         String           @db.ObjectId
  user           User             @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
```

It appears we are deliberately
[denormalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization),
perhaps for performance reasons.
I'm OK with that, especially if documented with a comment
that describes the tradeoffs.
Those tradeoffs may show up differently in future, and we will want to compare.

Alternatively, consider deleting one of those redundant columns
in favor of queries doing a JOIN.